# Hebrews 7:8; who is meant by the phrase "witnessed that he liveth", Melchizedek or Jesus Christ?

Tags: greek, hebrews, referent-identification, authorial-intent

Hebrews 7:8 (ASV):

> 8 And here men that die receive tithes; but there one, of whom **it is witnessed that he liveth.**

About whom is this phrase "of whom it is witnessed that he liveth" speaking: Melchizedek or Jesus Christ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh!  This is so contentious!  in Heb 7:8, Who is the antecedent (in English) of "he" in "he lives"? Or, in the Greek, what is the subject of the verb ζῇ (= "he lives")?

The obvious choice is "Melchizedek" but does this mean that the author of Hebrews is suggesting that Melchizedek was immortal and did not die?  To avoid this problem, Poole suggests that the referent is Christ, despite the fact that Christ is not mentioned previously in the text!

Grammatically, its antecedent can only be Melchizedek, literally.  However, as the earlier part of Heb 7 makes clear, Melchizedek is a type of Christ (Ps 110:4) as Albert Barnes makes clear:

> Of whom it is witnessed - Of whom the record is. There is not in
> Genesis, indeed, any direct record that he lives, but there is the
> absence of a record that he died, and this seems to have been regarded
> as in fact a record of permanency in the office; or as having an
> office which did not pass over to successors by the death of the then
> incumbent.
>
> **That he liveth** - This is an exceedingly difficult expression, and one which has always greatly perplexed commentators. The fair and
> obvious meaning is, that all the record we have of Melchizedek is,
> that he was "alive;" or as Grotins says, the record is merely that he
> lived. We have no mention of his death. From anything that the record
> shows, it might appear that he continued to live on, and did not die.
> "Arguing from the record," therefore, there is a strong contrast
> between him and the Levitical priests, all of whom we know are mortal;
> Hebrews 7:23. The apostle is desirous of making out a contrast between
> them and the priesthood of Christ on "this point" among others, and in
> doing this, he appeals to the record in the Old Testament, and says
> that there was a case which furnished an intimation that the priestly
> office of the Messiah was not to pass over from him to others by
> death.
>
> That case was, that he was expressly compared Psalm 110:4 with
> Melchizedek, and that in the account of Melchizedek there was no
> record of his death. As to the force of this argument, it must be
> admitted that it would strike a Jew more impressively than it does
> most readers now; and it may not be improbable that the apostle was
> reasoning from some interpretation of the passages in Genesis 14:and
> Psalm 110. which was then prevalent, and which would then be conceded
> on all hands to be correct. If this was the admitted interpretation,
> and if there is no equivocation, or mere trick in the reasoning - as
> there cannot be shown to be - why should we not allow to the Jew a
> uniqueness of reasoning as we do to all other people? There are modes
> of reasoning and illustration in all nations, in all societies, and in
> all professions, which do not strike others as very forcible. The
> ancient philosophers had methods of reasoning which now seem weak to
> us; the lawyer often argues in a way which appears to be a mere quirk
> or quibble, and so the lecturer in science sometimes reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Commentators are divided as to the intended referent. The Greek is ambiguous, and grammar alone cannot indicate to whom the third-person-singular ζῇ refers.

--

Poole's commentary suggests it is Christ:

> Nor can he, of whom it is witnessed that he liveth, be any other than
> Jesus, who, is the man that continueth for ever; and, is ever-living.

See verses 22-25 later in the chapter:

> 22 By so much was **Jesus** made a surety of a better testament.
>
> 23 And they truly were many priests, because they were not suffered to
> continue by reason of death:
>
> 24 But **this man** [Jesus], because he continueth ever, hath an unchangeable
> priesthood.
>
> 25 Wherefore he is able also to save them to the uttermost that come
> unto God by him, seeing **he ever liveth** to make intercession for them.

--

Barnes favors Melchizedek as the referent:

> That he liveth - This is an exceedingly difficult expression, and one
> which has always greatly perplexed commentators. The fair and obvious
> meaning is, that all the record we have of Melchizedek is, that he was
> "alive;" or as Grotins says, the record is merely that he lived. We
> have no mention of his death. From anything that the record shows, it
> might appear that he continued to live on, and did not die. "Arguing
> from the record," therefore, there is a strong contrast between him
> and the Levitical priests, all of whom we know are mortal [see Hebrews
> 7:23]. The apostle is desirous of making out a contrast between them
> and the priesthood of Christ on "this point" among others, and in
> doing this, he appeals to the record in the Old Testament, and says
> that there was a case which furnished an intimation that the priestly
> office of the Messiah was not to pass over from him to others by
> death.

--

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown commentary strikes a middle ground:

> "He who is made like to Him that liveth." Melchisedec "liveth" merely
> in his official capacity, his priesthood being continued in Christ.
> Christ, on the other hand, is, in His own person, "ever living after
> the power of an endless life" (Heb 7:16, 25). Melchisedec's death not
> being recorded, is expressed by the positive term "liveth," for the
> sake of bringing into prominence the antitype, Christ, of whom alone
> it is strictly and perfectly true, "that He liveth."

In this sense, the author of Hebrews would be referring specifically to Melchizedek in order to teach something about Christ, for whom Melchizedek is a type or symbol.

--

**Conclusion**

The referent may be ambiguous, but the broader point being made here is a contrast between the Levitical order and the Melchizedek order.

This contrast is brought to a climax 3 chapters later, in showing that salvation cannot come through the Levitical ordinances; it comes through Christ--a high priest forever after the order of Melchizedek:

> 11 And every priest standeth daily ministering and offering oftentimes
> the same sacrifices, which can never take away sins:
>
> 12 But this man [Jesus], after he had offered one sacrifice for sins for ever,
> sat down on the right hand of God;
>
> ...
>
> 14 For by one offering he hath perfected for ever them that are
> sanctified.

Jesus accomplished through His infinite sacrifice what no amount of Levitical ordinances ever could.